¿Cómo saber los paquetes que tengo instalados en R?
Tengo que reinstalar Windows por problemas que ya no puedo resolver. Instalé varios paquetes en R pero no sé cuáles. La ventana de paquetes no ayuda porque no hice instalaciones individuales. ¿puedo saber lo que instalé? ¿cómo? Gracias.

Si, puedes usar la función installed.packages(), de hecho podrías generar un script para ejecutar la instalación:
cat(sapply(installed.packages()[,"Package"],
       \(x) paste0("if (!('", x, "' %in% installed.packages())) install.packages('", x, "')")
), sep="\n")

La salida sera algo así:
..
if (!('tools' %in% installed.packages())) install.packages('tools')
if (!('utils' %in% installed.packages())) install.packages('utils')

Simplemente guardar en un archivo y correrlo luego de la reinstalación
